# What could be causing this encoding issue?

Tags: node.js, forms, http, browser, encoding

I have a nodeJS app using the expressJS framework, and MongoDB as data storage.

There is a form in which users can give data about project submissions in textarea and text type input fields.

There are reports, that when they copy and paste the values from another tab or application (Google Docs, Notepad++) into these fields and submit, the special characters are getting stored in their URLencoded format.

i.e.: `A, B, C` becomes `A%2C B%2C, C`

The strangest is that I haven't been able to reproduce the issue on either a MacOS or Windows system, while running a local instance of the NodeJS app using either Chrome, Firefox or Safari, but I keep seeing this issue popping up on the production instance.

Front end:

```
<form method="POST" action="/projects/submit" data-abide="data-abide" novalidate="novalidate" data-e="as8gke-e">
<input type="text" name="team_name" required="required">
...
</form>
```

Router:

```
router.post('/submit', function(req, res) {
    var pageData = {};
    ProjectRepository.save(req.body)
});
```

The function that handles mongoDB insertion:

```
ProjectRepository.prototype.save = function(document){
    var deferred = q.defer(),
        _self = this;

    MongoClient.connect()
        .then(function(db){
            return db.collection(_self.collection);
        })
        .then(function(collection){
            if(document._id){
                //Update existing record
                document.modified = moment().utc().toDate();
                collection.updateOne(
                    {_id:document._id},
                    { $set: document},
                    function(err, result){
                        if(err) return deferred.reject(err);
                        deferred.resolve(result);
                    }
                )
            }else{
                //Create new document
                document.created = moment().utc().toDate();
                collection.insertOne(
                    document,
                    function(err,result){
                        if(err) return deferred.reject(err);
                        deferred.resolve(result);
                    }
                )
            }
        });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Can anyone suggest how I could debug this? I suspect it has to do with server / client / application character encodings, but it's unusual that I'm not either seeing the full text in it's URL encoded form, only the non-whitespace non-alphanumeric characters...

Did anyone encounter this before?

Comment: It's going to be very hard to help debug this if you can't reproduce this and don't share any code. If this is a plain HTML form this shouldn't happen.

Comment: I've updated the question with the code snippets that handle saving the document to the DB.